# To get around the ajax 'same origin policy', code for a PHP ajax request forwarder?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy

I want to bypass the ajax same-origin policy by having a php page on my site that basically acts like a JSON proxy. Eg i make an ajax request like this:

```
mysite.com/myproxy.php?url=blah.com/api.json&a=1&b=2
```

It then makes a request to:

```
blah.com/api.json?a=1&b=2
```

And returns the JSON (or whatever) result to the original requester.
Now i assume i'd be stupidly reinventing the wheel if i wrote this php code (plus i don't know php!) - is there some pre-existing code to do this? I'm sure i'm not the only one who's butted my head up against the same-origin policy before.

Oh yeah JSONP isn't an option for this particular api.

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here's something - 
Slap this into a php script, call it like this
script.php?url=blah

post the contents you want posted to the server.

```
<?php


$curlPost = http_build_query($_POST);
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Now this script is a bit too open for my liking, so to increase security I would recommend that you add a list of domains to a white list.

So add this to the top:

```
$whitelist = array('http://www.google.com','http://www.ajax.com');
$list = array();
foreach($whitelist as $w)
 $list[] = parse_url($w,PHP_URL_HOST);

$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = pathinfo($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
if(!in_array($url, $list)) die('no access to that domain');
```

Comment: You missed the $ch param to the curl_exec... took a while to figure out!

Comment: WOrks great, thanks. This is only for development work so security shouldn't matter too much. Thanks again